# Linked list values changed when i want to print it

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, abstract-data-type

I want to print my doubly linked list. Here is the function

```
void show(que *q) {
    que *temp;
    temp = q;

    if (q->cnt == 0)
        printf ("\nEmpty.\n");
    else {
        while (temp->cnt > 0) {
            printf("%d[prioriy=%d]  cnt:%d\n", temp->fr->dat, temp->fr->priority);
            temp->fr = temp->fr->prv;
            temp->cnt--;
        }
    }
}
```

I assign struct element `q` to other element `temp`, and only modify `temp`, but why does the value of `q` also change? For example `q->cnt` becomes equal to zero, despite that I didn't modify it.

EDIT:

```
typedef int kintyr;

typedef struct qElem {
    struct qElem *prv;          
    kintyr *dat;                    
    int *priority;
} qElem;


typedef struct que {
    qElem *fr, *bk;             
    int cnt;                    
} que;
```

Comment: Show how que is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`q` and `temp` are both pointers, that is, they store addresses in memory. By modifying data that one of them points to, retrieving that data via the other pointer will reflect those changes because they both point to the same location in memory. The data itself is only stored in one place.

If you want to iterate over your list, you'll want a temporary pointer to a node, which you'll walk through the list using a local counter (instead of modifying the one in the list):

```
//Set a temporary node to point to the front of the queue
qElem *temp = q->fr;
//Create a local variable to track where in the queue we are
int cnt = q->cnt;
if(cnt==0)
    printf ("\nEmpty.\n");
else
{
    while(cnt>0)
    {
        printf( "%d[prioriy=%d]  cnt:%d\n", temp->dat, temp->priority );
        //Point to the next node in the queue
        temp = temp->prv;
        //Decrement our local counter
        cnt--;
    }

}
```

Comment: so how can I put the values of `temp` to other memory place? Is it even possible? Or how is there other way to print my `QUE`?

Comment: Can you add the definitions of your struct(s) to your question? Also this method is only for printing and shouldn't modify anything, correct?

Comment: Added. Yup it's only for printing.

Comment: @user2965303 Edited to add sample code for iterating over the queue (NB: I didn't fix the issue with your `printf()`)

Comment: can you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337289/implementing-adt-priority-que-as-linked-list-cant-sort-elements ?

Answer (score 0):

1. temp is also pointing to the memory of the q, change in the value of temp->cnt-- is same as the q->cnt--
2. Better you take the int count = q->cnt , operate on the count variable

Comment: thanks, can you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337289/implementing-adt-priority-que-as-linked-list-cant-sort-elements ? @

Answer (score 0):

`q` is an address to memory. You say that `temp` shall be an address to memory as well. This is due to `*`. When you assign `temp = q` you say that the address of `temp` shall go to the same address as `q` in memory. If you want a new `que` var don't use `*` before `temp`.